# MySQL Update query with multiple joins to the same table

Tags: mysql

In my existing project database (MySQL), there are 2 tables Employee and EmployeeReference.

[image]

Employee table has Role column which may be Employee (or) Manager

Each Manager will have a Reference Code and if they refer an employee that will be stored in EmployeeReference table. He will also have a record in EmployeeReference table with his own Reference Code.

Now we want to update this Reference Code column in EmployeeReference table with EmployeeID of the mangager, instead of existing Reference Code.

How to do this Update query in MySQL using multiple join within same table ? 
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Post your query .

Comment: Why not store the manager code in place of the employee type column? A manager is then simply an employee with no ( i.e. NULL) manager code

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand this problem then following query can work. it can be further optimized.

```
SELECT * FROM `EmployeeReference` c INNER JOIN (SELECT a.RefCode,a.EmpId FROM `EmployeeReference` a INNER JOIN Employee b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpId WHERE b.Role = 'MNG') d ON c.RefCode = d.RefCode  

UPDATE `EmployeeReference` c INNER JOIN (SELECT a.RefCode,a.EmpId FROM `EmployeeReference` a INNER JOIN Employee b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpId WHERE b.Role = 'MNG') d ON c.RefCode = d.RefCode SET c.RefCode = d.EmpId
```

Comment: Thank you ! This works like a charm but not updating few rows with Role other than 'MNG' / 'EMP',....for example there is another role 'ADM' which is also referred by one of the 'MNG'

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to get the expected result

```
SELECT er.*
FROM EmployeeReference er
LEFT JOIN Employee e 
 ON UPPER(Name) LIKE SUBSTRING(er.RefCode,1,3)+'%'
  AND e.Role = 'MNG'
  AND e.EmpID <> er.EmpID;
```

**Note: With the above query write your update query**

Hope this should help you out.